# Javascript backgroundImage url css change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to change the backgroundImage of a div in a parent iframe.

I can do it, but not in a useful way, I need to send the variable from the button.

At the moment I have the variable in the script.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
window.parent.document.getElementById('seekerBase').style.backgroundImage = "url('http://www.floom.com/images/waveform_lotos.gif')";
 }
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Get the background image of div</button>
```

I need to send the image url from the button and not having it in the script.

I tried this and is not working.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    window.parent.document.getElementById('seekerBase').style.backgroundImage = "url()";
     }
    </script>

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('http://www.floom.com/images/waveform_lotos.gif')">Get the background image of div</button>
```

Thanks for your help.
I am a newbie.

Comment: Pass it as a parameter `function myFunction(img) { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Background image URL, `http://www.floom.com/images/waveform_lotos.gif` , passed to `myFunction(bgImgUrl)` is basically a parameter to the function. For more information on *JavaScript Functions*, refer [Mozilla/Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

Try this!

```
<script>
  function myFunction(bgImgUrl) {
    window.parent.document.getElementById('seekerBase').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bgImgUrl + ')';
  }
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('http://www.floom.com/images/waveform_lotos.gif')">Get the background image of div</button>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Jürgen You're welcome! Please **accept** as **Answer** if it really helped. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I am new on this, I did it now ;)